# select name, COUNT(*) from two different tables as a query result

Tags: sql, oracle, count

```
CREATE TABLE    CUSTOMER (
cusID   VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
cusNAME     VARCHAR(50),
CONSTRAINT CUSTOMER_PKEY PRIMARY KEY (cusID)
);

CREATE TABLE    ORDERS (
cusID       VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
item    VARCHAR(25),
PPRICE  NUMBER(12,2),
CONSTRAINT ORDERS_FKEY FOREIGN KEY (cusID) REFERENCES CUSTOMER(cusID)
);
```

i have this two tables, and i want a query results of

```
CUSNAME    ITEM BOUGHT
JOHN          2
MAY           5
```

is it possible to do this?
something like select cusNAME,COUNT(*) FROM CUSTOMER,ORDERS .......and so on...
have no idea how to continue this.

Comment: please correct your question format , it isn't readable!

Comment: Is "bought" defined as the number of rows in the orders table? Or is there a quantity purchased amount somewhere?

Comment: bought is just how many times cusID appear in the orders table because   customer can only buy one item at a time. so i need to find out how many item has they bought

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  cus.cusName,
        COUNT(*) AS ItemBought
FROM    Customer AS cus
        INNER JOIN Orders AS ord
            ON cus.CusID = ord.cusID
GROUP   BY cus.cusName
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

The query above will only show when a customer has atleast one record on table `Order` because it uses `INNER JOIN`. If you want to show all customers whether it has atleast one record on table order or not, use `LEFT JOIN` instead.

Comment: @downvoter you have so many chances to downvote my answers. clearly `:)` happy downvoting.